# What are Bayes Factors and how can they be used to demonstrate a null finding of "no difference" between two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology, bayes-factors

A prominent journal in my field recently updated its advice to [authors to state](http://www.addictionjournal.org/pages/authors#requirements):

> **Null findings**: Authors should only report ‘no difference’ between
>   conditions or lack of associations if they can demonstrate this by
>   calculating Bayes Factors. A Bayes Factor of less than 0.3 would
>   normally be required to be confident that there really is no
>   difference or association. Otherwise null findings should be framed as
>   ‘the findings were inconclusive as to whether or not a
>   difference/association was present’ or some similar wording.

While I understand that in classical NHT, null findings do not demonstrate 'no difference', I am unfamiliar with Bayes Factors and their uses.

**What are Bayes Factors? How can they be calculated? How should they be interpreted, including to demonstrate a null finding of "no difference" between two groups?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from [a paper by Robert West](http://doi.org/10.1111/add.13053View):

> The Bayes Factor (BF) is a ratio showing the degree to which a set of
>   data (even just one data point), changes the probability that a given
>   hypothesis (H1) is true versus an alternative hypothesis (H0). If the
>   BF is 1, then the data support (or fail to support) both hypotheses
>   equally and are thus completely uninformative on the matter. If the BF
>   is 3 then, given these data, H1 is three times more likely to be
>   correct than H0. If the BF is 1/3 then H0 is three times more likely
>   to be correct than H1.
>
> It so happens that a BF of 3 is found typically when in classical
>   frequentist statistics the P-value would be 0.05 on the same data, and
>   so 3 and 1/3 are used commonly as thresholds for statements that there
>   is substantial evidence for one or other hypothesis being correct [3].
>   For different decisions one may wish to use different thresholds.
>
> Suppose one has undertaken a study of 300 people (150 in each group)
>   comparing gradual and abrupt methods for smoking cessation and finds
>   an odds ratio favouring abrupt cessation of 1.56 [95% confidence
>   interval (CI) = 0.77–3.11, P = 0.22]. Thus, using the classical
>   hypothesis testing approach, we would say there was no statistically
>   significant difference and researchers often conclude that there is
>   ‘no effect’. With a Bayesian approach we can go further. We could
>   specify in advance two hypotheses: H0 as the hypothesis that the odds
>   ratio in the population is 1 (i.e. there is no difference), and H1 as
>   the hypothesis that there is a clinically useful and plausible
>   advantage to abrupt cessation of something between 1.1 and 3.0. We can
>   calculate a BF to tell us which of these is most likely from the data
>   and by how much. In fact, it turns out to be 1.5, which means that H1
>   is 50% more likely than H0. The appropriate conclusion, then, is that
>   the data favour the hypothesis of a clinically important difference
>   relative to none at all, but not strongly. This is more informative
>   than simply concluding that there is no statistically significant
>   difference and more accurate than asserting that there is ‘no effect’.

Functions to calculate Bayes Factors in R can be found at:
http://www.danny-kaye.co.uk/Docs/Dienes_functions.txt